# What happened to this character at the end of "Fringe" season 5?

Tags: time-travel, fringe

So I've read many theories about all the time paradoxes of the *Fringe* season 5 ending. But what I can't seem to find an answer to is this:

Walter was supposed to take the last inoculation which enables him to travel to 2167 with Michael. But September took the last inoculation shot and decided to take Michael himself. Of course, September gets shot in the end and Walter Bishop is forced to take Michael to 2167 by himself.

What I don't understand is the inoculation part. Since Walter didn't get his shot, does it mean he didn't survive the trip? If that is so, then in a sense, September doomed Walter to not being able to travel to 2167.

However, we know that timeline did reset, so it means Michael reached the doctors and Observers were erased. Does this then mean that Walter did survive the time travel? If so, what was the point of the inoculation?

Comment: Great first question!

Comment: Oh alright thanks @TheAsh. Somehow i thought since he was in the amber for so long he needed a second inoculation before going. Apparently it was just a back up if someone else needs it. So Walter survived after all, that's great.

Comment: He ended up in Middle Earth as the steward of Gondor

Comment: Not sure we need information-free questions for a 10-year-old episode

Answer (score 8):

From the script:

> WALTER: It's an inoculation for time travel. I'm taking the child Observer into the future, Peter. I was already inoculated in 2015. I left this one in case something happened to me and someone else had to bring the boy across to complete the plan.

So, Walter already had it.

Edit: I found the scene on YT:
[Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pb840BkY85M&t=117s)

Comment: Which episode was that, I've seen Fringe several times from end to end and I don't remember this scene, it may not have been translated this way in all languages.

Comment: @AaarghZombies I haven't seen the show in years, so I don't know. I just looked for the transcript online. It's the last episode.